# HttpClient, WebApi and string

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have trouble with date and strings...

my service method is

```
`
[Route("Assign/{eventId}/{description}")]
[HttpPost]
public void AssignEvent(int eventId, string description)
{
      base.RepositoryEvent.UpdateEventAssignedTo(eventId, description);
}
`
```

even with swagger, if i put "tototo..." in description then it crash with 404 because of dots

and I understand that "http://localhost/Atlas.SSUP.Web.Api.Rest/Event/Assign/121212/totot..." is not ok

any help ?

Comment: And your controller has a Route attribute that corresponds to your root path ("Atlas.SSUP.Web.Api.Rest/Event")?

Comment: yes all is ok if I remove the dots in the description

Comment: I recreated this method on a Asp.Net Core 3.1 WebAPI project, and it worked, even with the dots.  What platform/version are you using?  Core or Framework?

Comment: Version Microsoft .NET Framework :4.0.30319; Version ASP.NET :4.8.3928.0

Comment: if I debug the call from swagger, i don't get in the controller and method...maybe the WebApiConfig

Comment: for the one interrested, i solved that by using post with json struct and no more inline params. btw, thanks